# Simple CSS code not working. Menu bar doesn't show the right color when selecting a tab. Please

Tags: html, css

beginner girl here who is completely stuck at her first CSS project. Please please tell me what I am doing wrong.

So I have this horizontal menu, with three stupid tabs. I want the background color for the selected tab to be different (done!), and also the font color to be different - which is not happening, despite by best efforts for the past hour.

This is the HTML:

```html
  <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="tema.html">Job Description Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Audit Trail</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Files</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

And the CSS. Here the background property for the last rule IS APPLIED. But if I add a color one, nothing happens. Does the code have a grudge against me? :(

```css
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
  background-color: #488AC7;
  margin: none;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
nav ul li a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #F0FFFF;
  border-bottom: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul li.selected {
  background-color: #F0FFFF;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
nav ul li.selected a, nav ul li.selected a:visited {color:red;}
```

Comment: Aziz, you're a genius! It worked! (one small addition though, after the first 'a' I've added :link, so that the color would stick).

Comment: you're welcome. it's not really necessary to have `a:link`.. usually people just write `a { }`

Comment: nice shortcut, thanks again! off-topic: I've just finished the stupid menu and I have the whole page to finish. Panicking. Deadline is Monday morning.

Comment: You can do it! if you face any problems you can always ask questions on stackoverflow, welcome to the community and good luck with your project

Comment: Don't forget the mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: @rac - already marked it, of course, but nothing is displayed because I have a < 15 level.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
nav ul li.selected a {
    color:red; 
}
```

Color on `nav ul li.selected` is applied to the text that are no links. You have to specify the color for the links with `nav ul li.selected a`.